# DBContext creates the mdf file but doesn't attach it to SQL Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My web.config file has the following string:

```
<add name="myAwesomeDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myAwesomeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My dbContext:

```
public myContext() : base("myAwesomeDB")
{
}
```

Here's my dilemma: I can't for the life of me find where this database is. Based on the connection string, it should be attached to my SQLEXPRESS instance on localhost (my dev machine), but when I log in using SQL Management Studio, it's not listed under the Databases node. The .mdf file exists in my project location.

What is bizarre is that I can create, edit and delete records. I just don't understand what is managing the database.

**Update:** If I feed a string to the DBContext constructor for which there is no connection string, then the database gets created under SQL Express.

Using VS 2015.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: Ok... I thought that if both LocalDB and SQL Server Express are installed, the latter will be preferred. How do I modify the connection string to force it to use SQL Server Express rather than LocalDB?

Comment: try `Initial Catalog` in your connection string.

Comment: That kinda worked, but I also had to remove `User Instance=True` from the connection string.